# blocking audio app for node.js and electron

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, mp3

I'm using nodejs and ubuntu 21.10. I have an electron app that has to play an mp3 file. Presently I do this by launching a system app to play the file. I want to know when the playback has finished. I have tried mplayer and mpg123. They seem to work similarly. I issue the command to play the file and the app I use, mplayer or mpg123, returns right away before the mp3 finished playing.

If you were to launch the player playing the file from the command line, the playback is acompanied by some changing textual display on the screen. I think these players play the track in a separate thread. I want something that blocks until the track is done.

The reason I want this is that I'm using the microphone immediately after the playback. I don't want the mic listening to the playback. Presently I use a timer to wait 3 seconds before going to the microphone, but that's not the best, I'm sure.

I think my code looks like this now:

```
const out = execSync("mpg123 ./sample.mp3");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a system app? Libraries like [Plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr), for example (I'm not affiliated with them but have used the library), provide an easy API to HTML5 media playback. Through [events](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#events) you'd know when the playback has ended. Should I sum that up into an answer?

Comment: i will try it out. I don't want video, just audio, and no player. I just want sound to come out of the speakers. That's all. Looking at Plyr for the first time the importing into my js script isn't working. I will try a little further.

Comment: Well, you can create an Audio player with Plyr and for example hide the controls and/or create it in an element which has `display: none`. Re. import is not working, I'm pretty sure that this is a fixable problem, given the context of the error.

Comment: nope. it additionally needs to run from the thread where the main.js runs... where the electron menus are and file saving happens. that's probably why the importing does not work.

Comment: Why would you have to do this? Remember, you can listen to the `ended` event Plyr emits in the renderer and then send a message to the main process (Node.js) via IPC.

Comment: can you show some code with 'ended' in it. I cannot seem to get this to work. I'm using vue-plyr. Also I can get it to play once, but then the subsequent times it does not load the new audio clip, though it has changed.

Comment: I have moved, at least for the moment, to using the built in 'Audio()' constructor.